# consulta sobre tablas en sql

Tags: sql

Miren, tengo una tabla1 en la cuál existe una columna del código y en otra tabla2 tengo en una columna el código y en otra columna tengo una descripción; mi consulta es de como puedo hacer que se visualice la descripción cuando consulto datos de la tabla1 pero internamente se mantenga el código en la tabla1.

estoy intentando con select´s aninados más no entiendo el funcionamiento con relación a lo que busco, me vendría de maravilla una mano para poder llevar a cabo esto que me he propuesto.

estoy trabajando con SQL.

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: Tal y como dice @alfap muestranos que has intentando, por favor. Necesitamos saber sobre que lenguaje estás trabajando, PHP, Java, SQL...Ver que código tienes hecho hasta ahora. Echa un ojo a [ask] y a [mcve] y actualiza la pregunta en consecuencia. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de la propia claúsula FROM indica el nombre de las dos tablas:

Por lo que entiendo tienes **Tabla 1: código** y **Tabla 2: código + descripción** y quieres consultar el código de la primera y la descripción.

`SELECT b.descripción
 FROM   Tabla 1 a, Tabla 2 b
 WHERE  a.codigo = b.codigo`

Espero te haya ayudado. A esta operación se le conoce como JOIN (unir tablas).

Un saludo

Comment: y por decir si tienes una descripción ya establecida con un nombre pero que cuando haces la consulta, a esa descripción de determinado código le quieres cambiar de nombre solo para verla como se lo puede hacer?, yo tengo la idea de que viene a ser como un condición más al "where"...

Comment: Te refieres a nombrar la columna???