# consulta con condición en sql

Tags: sql

tengo dos tablas:

tabla1: código,otra,otra,otra

tabla2: código,nombre

la consulta con la que me ayudaron para poder visualizar el nombre de acorde al código es:

select a.codigo, b.nombre
from tabla1 a, tabla2 b
where a.codigo = b.codigo

mi nueva inquietud es que si ya tengo un nombre establecido, como puedo hacer para que en cierto nombre me muestre otro nombre cuando mando una consulta pero no afecto el nombre ya existente (no quiero hacer update).

ESTOY TRABAJANDO EN SQL. Gracias de antemano.

es decir en tabla1 tengo el nombre, apellido, y código de la ciudad donde vive; y en tabla2 tengo los códigos de la ciudades, el nombre de las ciudades.

ej: en la consulta de resultados tengo "miami" en algunas tuplas, pero en vez de que me aparezca "miami" me gustaria cambiarle a "orlando", pero en la tabla2 no le quiero cambiar "miami" por "orlando".

Comment: Posible duplicado de [consulta sobre tablas en sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245694/consulta-sobre-tablas-en-sql)

Comment: Si colocaras algo mas de informacion, como por ejemplo: una pequeña porcion de los datos que tiene cada tabla y adicional cuales son los nombres a reemplazar. Tambien agrega una etiqueta o por lo menos informa cual es el motor de base de datos que estas usando, La etiqueta SQL no dice nada.

Comment: Y pues por lo que veo, lo que necesitas es tener una tabla temporal con los nombre a reemplazar y realizar un ***right join*** o un ***left join*** el que venga al caso. Ó simplemente si es un query sencillo utilizar un ***with***, si te lo permite la base de datos. Tambien tienes la opcion de ***case*** si son pocos nombre a reemplazar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo como datos:

```
create table datos (
 id int,
 nombre varchar(50)
);

insert into datos (id,nombre) values 
 (1,"jose"),
 (2,"pedro"),
 (3,"maria"),
 (4,"erika");
```

Para lograr el cometido se puede utilizar la sentencia "CASE" la cual evalúa una condición y si es true entonces podemos definir un retorno, bien sea un valor especificado directamente como también un subquery.

```
select id, 
 case when nombre = 'pedro' then 'pedrito' else nombre end as nombre
from datos;
```

Se selecciona el campo id, seguido del case: cuando el campo nombre es igual a 'pedro' entonces coloca 'pedrito' sino coloca lo que esté en la columna nombre y se finaliza el case, se coloca as nombre para que la expresión quede con ese nombre de columna.

Te dejo el link para pruebas (primero le das build eschema y luego run sql):
[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bd15b/3)

**EDITO**:

En tu caso específico debería ser:

```
 select case when a.codigo = 'miami' then 'orlando' else a.codigo end codigo, b.nombre from tabla1 a, tabla2 b where a.codigo = b.codigo
```

Comment: no me sirvió con lo que estoy buscando ya que necesito ver el código de la otra tabla que había mencionado antes

Comment: Es un ejemplo tienes que adaptarlo pensando en tu query.

Comment: si lo hice, pero me dió error al momento de ejecutarla